# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataView' to type 'System.Data.IDataReader'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataview, idatareader

I have a function (on vb.net) to get a data from a XMLWebService:

```
Private Function GetDataSchedule() As DataTable
    Dim xTable As Data.DataTable
    xTable = xMaster.GetSchedule()

    'Bind to DataTable
    Dim DT As New System.Data.DataTable
    DT.Load(xTable.DefaultView) '--> When I set a breakpoint, the error start from here

    Return DT
End Function
```

And then the function to call the `GetDataSchedule()` Function:

```
Public Sub ShowDataSchedule()
    Dim DSSchedule As New System.Data.DataSet
    DSSchedule.Tables.Add(GetDataSchedule) 

End Sub
```

But then when I executed the code, it results on get the error message:
`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataView' to type 'System.Data.IDataReader'.`

When I just execute the `GetDataSchedule()` Function, it return value, but when I make it separately to call the function, then it got error. Am I missing something? Need your help. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DSSchedule.Tables.Add(GetDataSchedule().Copy())
```

Although, since you might get back a null reference from GetDataSchedule(), it would be better to re factor your code a bit:

```
Dim schedule as Data.DataTable = GetDataSechedule()
If Not IsNothing(schedule) Then
    DSSchedule.Tables.Add(schedule.Copy())
End If
```

Otherwise, your code will go **boom** if you try to perform a `.Copy()` on a null reference.

Comment: Hi, thanks.. It doesn't work. I still got the message, and I think the problem is not get back a nullreference, but I'm not sure enough..

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I think the solution to your problem is the Copy() method above. The null reference check was something extra I added.

Answer (score 0):

The Load function accepts only DataReaders as arguments (eg: SqlDataReader), but you already have a datatable. It should be enough to have DT = xTable.